# How to fix SQL error when querying based on date value in a where statement?

Tags: sql, date, format, where-clause

```
select 
    pid, last_name, first_name, 
    cast(CONVERT(varchar, birth_date, 23) as datetime) as DOB
from 
    TABLE
where  
    (last_name = 'Doe' and birth_date = '1999-09-09' and pid = '1234567') or
    (last_name = 'Doet' and birth_date = '1999-09-19' and pid = '12345678')
```

I have a lot of last names to pull. This is just showing two examples. As the list goes too long I got the error message as:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

When I only query less than 500, no error at all.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific query.)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as well as an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times the problem is with the time zone setting. Specify in other formats like mm/dd/yyyy (usually works).

If you need to convert your input the you can try looking into the CONVERT method. Syntax is

CONVERT(VARCHAR,@your_date_Value,103)

CONVERT(VARCHAR, '12/30/2013', 103)

The finishing 103 is the datetime format.

Refer this link for conversion formats and further reading. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Answer (score 1):

First, why are you converting at all?  just use:

```
select pid, last_name, first_name, birth_date
```

If you want birthdate in a special format, then (whatever "23" is) convert it to a string:

```
select pid, last_name, first_name, convert(varchar(255), birth_date, 23)
```

There is no need to convert back to a string. Do note the length with `varchar`. The default length varies by context and leaving out an explicit length is just begging for a hard-to-debug error.

Hopefully, `birth_date` is not a string, because that would be a sign of a bad data model.